# Is it possible to write polyrhythm in Guitar Pro 6?

Tags: guitar-pro

I want to create a polyrhythmic track on Guitar Pro 6. Let's say that I want the guitar to play 4/4 and the bass to play 6/4. Is it possible to write it on Guitar Pro? If yes, how?

If I try to change the time signature in one of the instruments, it changes for the other ones as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The time signature is always applied to all the tracks.
I think that they said they will support polyrhythm in the next version but don't hold your breath on that :-).

Comment: Still not possible in version 7.5